# Manipular JSON com jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Tenho um jQuery com `$.ajax` que envia uma requisição para o meu `config.php` que por sua vez retorna um `json_array`:

```
function enviar(){
    var bin = $("#bin_id").val();
    var linhaenviar = bin.split("\n");
    var index = 0;
    linhaenviar.forEach(function(value){

        setTimeout(
        function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'config.php',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'html',
                data: "bin=" + value,
                success: function(resultado){
            }
        })

    }, 10 * index);

    index = index + 1;

    })
}
```

O array retornado é este:

```
"{\"pergunta\":\"qual a cor do céu\",\"resposta\":\"azul\",\"status\":\"acertou\"}"
```

O que não entendo é como fazer para manipular esses dados que o `config.php` retorna, printando as respostas erradas na `div id="erro"` de acordo com o status.

Comment: Devias estar a usar `dataType: 'json'` em vez de `dataType: 'html'`

Comment: é que esse ajax faz a requisição enviando dados para um php que vai gerar o json com os dados enviados, se eu alterar mudaria algo no envio desses dados ?

Comment: Não, o `dataType ` só se refere ao retorno esperado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antes de mais nada, conforme mencionado nos comentários, troque o `dataType: 'html'` para `dataType: 'json'` (o retorno será um objeto JSON).

A variável de retorno `resultado` será o JSON, sendo assim, basta pegar o valor `status` com `resultado.status` e fazer a comparação se a resposta está correta:

```
function enviar(){
    var bin = $("#bin_id").val();
    var linhaenviar = bin.split("\n");
    var index = 0;
    linhaenviar.forEach(function(value){

        setTimeout(
        function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'config.php',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'html',
                data: "bin=" + value,
                success: function(resultado){
                    if(resultado.status != "acertou"){
                        $("#erro").append("Resposta errada<br>");
                    }
            }
        })

    }, 10 * index);

    index = index + 1;

    })
}
```

Comment: Obrigado deu certo :)